# Filter each inner property arrays with Ramda

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, ramda.js

I have an object like this:

```
const arrays = {
  one: [[1, 33, 41], [2, 0, 27], [3, 7, 9], [4, 1, 3]],
  two: [[1, 77, 2], [2, 6, 3], [3, 0, 0], [4, 55, 3]],
  three: [[1, 4, 6], [2, 0, 0], [3, 5, 6], [4, 0, 0]],
};
```

As you can see each **first number** is equal:

**1** for each first **inner array**

**2** for each second **inner array**

**3** for each third **inner array**

etc...

I want to **filter** based on the **first number** of each array
and some comparator number e.g. [3]

If we have a filter number [3] (**smaller or equal to 3**),
the wanted result would be:

```
const arrays = {
  one:   [[1,33,41], [2,0,27], [3,7,9]],
  two:   [[1,77,2],  [2,6,3],  [3,0,0]],
  three: [[1,4,6],   [2,0,0],  [3,5,6]],
};
```

Since all **first numbers** of inner arrays are smaller than or equal to **3**.
The arrays starting with 4,5... are ignored.

What would be the ramda's way to have this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like Ramda's `map` function because it can iterate over the properties of an object (and so avoid `Object.fromEntries` & `Object.entries`)  and apply a function to each one of them. That function is `filter` which will take as argument the inner arrays. The function given to `filter` is itself a composition of `gte` and `head`; takes the first element of an array and compare it with 3:

```
const arrays =
  { one:   [[1, 33, 41], [2, 0, 27], [3, 7, 9], [4,  1, 3]]
  , two:   [[1, 77,  2], [2, 6,  3], [3, 0, 0], [4, 55, 3]]
  , three: [[1,  4,  6], [2, 0,  0], [3, 5, 6], [4,  0, 0]] };

   map(filter(compose(gte(3), head)), arrays);
// ^   ^      ^       ^       ^
// A   B      C       D       E

//=> { one:   [[ 1, 33, 41], [2, 0, 27], [3, 7, 9]]
//=> , two:   [[ 1, 77,  2], [2, 6,  3], [3, 0, 0]]
//=> , three: [[ 1,  4,  6], [2, 0,  0], [3, 5, 6]] }
```

- map over each property (**A**); each array is passed to *filter* (**B**)
- Each inner array is passed to *compose* (**C**)
- Take the head of each inner array (**E**) and compare with 3 (**D**)

---

Scott Christopher rightly pointed out in the comments that `gte` can be confusing when partially applied. In fact the whole composition can be replaced with this simple lambda: `([x]) => x <= 3`.

Alternative solution which I like too:

```
map(filter(([x]) => x <= 3), arrays);
```

Comment: `R.gte` and friends are unfortunately notorious for causing confusion when partially applied. Perhaps subjective, though for the sake of readability I would suggest swapping out the argument provided to `R.filter` with a lambda to achieve the same (e.g. `([x]) => x <= 3`)

Comment: @ScottChristopher Agreed 100%. I added your suggested alternative to the answer. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'd totally subscribe for @customcommander's approach,
just wanted to add that you can also pass `numerical indexes` to [`R.propSatisfies`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#propSatisfies).

```js
const headIs3OrBelow = R.propSatisfies(R.gte(3), 0);
const fn = R.map(R.filter(headIs3OrBelow));

// ===
const data = {
  one: [[1, 33, 41], [2, 0, 27], [3, 7, 9], [4, 1, 3]],
  two: [[1, 77, 2], [2, 6, 3], [3, 0, 0], [4, 55, 3]],
  three: [[1, 4, 6], [2, 0, 0], [3, 5, 6], [4, 0, 0]],
};

console.log(
  fn(data),
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-3sdB9mAxNh2MIo6YkY05uY1qjkywAlDfCf5u1cSotv6k9CZUSyHVf4BJSpTYgla+YHLaHG8LUpqV7MHctlYzlw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

---

Also agree that `gte` and other similar methods are very difficult to read, because they kind of read backwards as `is 3 gte than x`... in Haskell you could do something like:

```hs
3 `gte` x
```

---

Vanilla approach:

```js
const headIs3OrBelow = ([head]) => head <= 3;

const fn = (data) => Object.entries(data).reduce(
  (res, [k, lists]) => ({ ...res, [k]: lists.filter(headIs3OrBelow) }),
  {},
);

// ===
const data = {
  one: [[1, 33, 41], [2, 0, 27], [3, 7, 9], [4, 1, 3]],
  two: [[1, 77, 2], [2, 6, 3], [3, 0, 0], [4, 55, 3]],
  three: [[1, 4, 6], [2, 0, 0], [3, 5, 6], [4, 0, 0]],
};

console.log(
  fn(data),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand you would like to use Ramda, this is not a solution using the library but accomplishes the same. You could create an object `from entries` that are `filtered` by comparing the first array value `a[0]` to the `maxVal` passed to the function.

```js
const arrays = {
  one: [[1, 33, 41], [2, 0, 27], [3, 7, 9], [4, 1, 3]],
  two: [[1, 77, 2], [2, 6, 3], [3, 0, 0], [4, 55, 3]],
  three: [[1, 4, 6], [2, 0, 0], [3, 5, 6], [4, 0, 0]],
};

const filterArrays = (arsObj, maxVal) => {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(arsObj).map(([k, v]) => {
    return [k, v.filter((a) => a[0] <= maxVal)];
  }));
}

const result = filterArrays(arrays, 3);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you @axtck, just we try to "enforce" Ramda. It helps leverage one step further the functional approach of programming. I kind like it, but sometimes it comes more time consuming.